# Difficulties to start Ethereum json RPC

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc, connections

I installed Ethereum on VPS and I have two accounts. 
After I installed Ethereum on my mac where I have one account. 
For now I'm on testnet network.

I want to connect to VSP accounts from mac terminal. 
I tried to do this :

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx" console
```

(xxx.xx.xxx.xxx) is the VPS IP

But when I do :

```
personal.listAccounts
```

I have just one account so I'm no connect to VSP but to my mac account .

How can I do to connect to VPS account?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to connect your local geth to a remote geth by rpc?

Comment: @5chdn, Yes this what I want to do. My first idea was by rpc but if there is an other way I'm buying

Comment: @5chdn, Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Insecure approach**:

On the remote machine run **geth** with the following arguments:

```
--rpc --rpcapi "admin,personal,db,eth,net,web3" --rpcport "8080"--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"
```

They are detailed [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8327/how-can-i-use-internet-to-carry-out-transactions-that-i-do-from-geth-console/8328#8328), [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/how-can-i-expose-geths-rpc-server-to-external-connections) and [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs).

On the local machine run:

```
$ geth attach rpc:http://<remote_ip>:8080
```

**(More) Secure Approach**

Connect to the VPS via SSH and run **geth** locally (without setting the **rpcaddr** argument) and connect to it through IPC:

```
$ geth attach ipc:/path/to/ipc
```

where the path is either the directory **geth** has been launched in or the custom **--datadir** passed as an argument to it.

Comment: Why your second solution is more secure ?

Comment: You use an SSH tunnel to connect the two machines and manage the remote station meaning that only people who have credentials/certificates for that SSH connection can connect to the remote machine whereas in the first anyone knowing the network address and port of the remote geth instance can connect to it. If you have an account that's unlocked (and the eth module loaded) then someone can transfer all your balance in that account to anther they control.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable personal via the `--rpcapi` switch. Here are some switch options:

`--rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3"`